# How can I turn a mirrored image of an object into a natural perspective of itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computer-vision

I am trying to get the 3D mapping of a fast moving object and only have 1 high fps camera on-hand. Thus I am opting for a setup using a mirror to reflect the 2nd perspective to my camera. The software package I am using is sensitive and does not respond well to mirrored images so I need to remove all the distortion caused by the mirror - which goes beyond a simple flip :(. If the mirrored image is reflected at an angle (I plan on using ~50 degrees), then the reflected image will have a perspective issue. I.e. the area of the reflected image closer to the camera will appear to move more than the objects in the back. Is there any way to undistort this?